# Fiddler request to WCF is failing with 504 ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request

Tags: wcf, json, .net-4.0, fiddler

Relevant Service Code:

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="products")]
public Product[] GetAllProduct()
{
    return ProductProvider.Instance.GetAllProducts();
}

[OperationContract]
Product[] GetAllProduct();
```

Relevant Configuration Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProductEntityDataModel.csdl|res://*/ProductEntityDataModel.ssdl|res://*/ProductEntityDataModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=PC\MSSQL2008;initial catalog=Test;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="Service.Default">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:1651/Default.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service.IDefault"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Relevant Fiddler Request

[image: Fiddler Request]

Comment: I couldn't imagine it would matter, but you have `ResponseFormat=JSON` in you directive twice.

Comment: Oh, one is RequestFormat and one is ResponseFormat.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can debug through the service and the service is not throwing any exceptions. I can return a string and it will work fine, however, when I try to return an object, that's when it fails. The object is both [Serializable()] and [DataContractSerializable(IsReference=true)]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting a content-type on the request if you're not doing a POST with a body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had issues with URITemplate in the past. Can you try:

```
[WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public Product[] products()
{
    return ProductProvider.Instance.GetAllProducts();
}

[OperationContract]
Product[] products();
```

Comment: Tried both WrappedResponse, then eliminated the URiTemplate, and replaced it with the function name in Fiddler.

Comment: @Kant, i found this article with a couple possible solutions: http://geekswithblogs.net/JamesFleming/archive/2011/03/09/wcf-http-504-working-on-a-mystery.aspx

Comment: @Joe Your link helped point me to use tracing to identify the issue, which turned out to be a failure to serialize.

Answer (score 0):

This may because of a DateTime type property in your class which is DateTime.MinValue (0001-01-01) by default.

I had exactly the same problem and resolved it by setting the date to a bigger value.

Also you should pay attention to any property which can not directly be serialized to JSON, such as TimeSpan, DateTimeOffset etc.

Answer (score 0):

we have same problem. I found something relevant answer here:

[WCF DataContractSerializer has a limit of 65536 object in the object graph](http://professionalaspnet.com/archive/2010/09/01/ReadResponse_28002900_-failed_3A00_-The-server-did-not-return-a-response-for-this-request_2E00_.aspx)

Hope it would help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Fiddler (v2.3.9.3) with a service using a BasicHttpBinding; I was able to fix it by changing the `transferMode` on the binding to `Streamed` (the default is `Buffered`), and then put Fiddler in Streaming Mode (make sure the "Stream" button on the toolbar is in the selected/pressed state).

# Chris

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and the problem was the object graph limit mentioned in the link that user72213 posted.

Modifying this limit using the [`ServiceBehaviorAttribute.MaxItemsInObjectGraph`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.maxitemsinobjectgraph.aspx) property did the trick for me.

You can also try the [`<dataContractSerializer>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731809.aspx)'s `maxItemsInObjectGraph` attribute, but using the attribute was more convenient in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem when returned dateTime object was null. It runs fine while debugging and gives problems while desalinizing. 
One way is to make your dateTime null able DateTime? and it will be deserialized correctly.

Hope helpful for someone.